# Is Eclipse's null check analysis confused by JUnit's 'fail'?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have the following code:

```
Object foo = someMethod();
if (foo == null) 
    org.junit.Assert.fail("OMG what a horrible error!");
foo.doSomeStuff();
```

But Eclipse (Neon, M4.6) seems to be unable to detect that that `org.junit.Assert.fail` method will terminate execution flow, and complains that the last line contains a possible NPE, which it doesn't.

Is that a bug or am I using it wrong ?

Comment: Do you use any build tools , like maven gradle ?

Comment: It is a Maven project, but it's built with Eclipses internal build system, which configures itself based on my pom.xml

Comment: Do you have Junit dependency in you pom ?

Comment: Of course. The code is working fine, it's just the Eclipse null checker that is misbehaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has a built in list of a few methods which it knows will not return. This includes the JUnit `assertNotNull` but does not include `fail`.

Eclise bug [382069](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382069) describes this support.

Comment: Yes, that seems about right. Is there any way to extend the list ? I mean, short of making a PR for the Eclipse code base.

Comment: @YorrikStorrick No, the list is hard coded in the source.

Answer (score 1):

How is Eclipse supposed to know that? As far as it's concerned this is just another library call.

If you use it like this it should work without a NullPointerException:

```
Object foo = someMethod();
if (foo == null) {
   org.junit.Assert.fail("Jesus Christ what a horrible error!");
} else {
   foo.doSomeStuff();
}
```

Comment: Well, it does know that the `assertNotNull` method is not just another library call, so it seems reasonable to assume that it would know about the much more generic and wide spread `fail` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if Assert.fail() would not throw an exception, you would have an NPE. But why would Eclipse / Java know that.

Btw, it's better to use assertNotNull, so you won't have that problem anyway...